# How can I redirect debug information to a text file in an expect script?

Tags: expect

My shebang looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
```

And when I run the script from the command line, it gives me what I want.

However, I am running this script via crontab. Is it possible to leave the debug switch on and let it keep writing to a debug log of some kind?

Answer (score 4):

You have to make use of `exp_internal` with flag as `-f` and the file name to which logging has to happen.

An output file name must follow either `0` or `1`. The 0 or 1 disables or enables the generation of diagnostics just as before.

[image]

The form `exp_internal -f file 0` is particularly useful because Expect appears to act just as if no diagnostics were being generated, even though it is actually writing the usual output and diagnostics to a file at the same time. You can put this particular command in production scripts and users will not be affected by the command. If a user then reports a bug, you can check the file and see exactly what went wrong.

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
exp_internal -f debug_info.log 0; # This is where the magic is happening ;)
expect {
        quit { exit }
        -re "(.+)\n" { puts "you typed $expect_out(1,string)";exp_continue}
        timeout { puts "I am waiting for you";exp_continue }
}
```

If you run this program, we can get the debugging information in the file named `debug_info.log` which will be stored in the current directory. (i.e. it is relative path. You can also give absolute path too, like /home/JLLouthan/somelogdir/mylog.log )

You can make this file name as a dynamic also. For example, you can give this as a command line argument too.

```
if {$argc!=1} {
        puts "Usage : $argv0 <debug-file>"
        exit
}

lassign $argv input_file
exp_internal -f $input_file 0
```

**Note :** `exp_internal` commands can be placed around pieces of code to limit the amount of diagnostics they produce. Each `exp_internal` command closes any previous file that was named by an `exp_internal` command.

So you can log different parts of a script to different files. When the script ends, any open `exp_internal` file is closed.

Reference : [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

Answer (score 2):

You could redirect stderr to the debug log file:

```
/path/to/script.exp >/var/log/stdout.log 2>/var/log/debug.log
```

A little browse through the expect man page reveals:

> exp_internal [-f file] value
>
> > causes  further  commands to send diagnostic information internal to Expect to stderr if value
> >     is non-zero.  This output is disabled if value is  0.   The  diagnostic  information  includes
> >     every  character received, and every attempt made to match the current output against the patterns.
> >
> > If the optional file is supplied, all normal and debugging output  is  written  to  that  file
> >     (regardless of the value of value).  Any previous diagnostic output file is closed.

So you want, at the top of the expect script:

```
exp_internal -f /var/log/debug/log 1
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that within the script?

Comment: @Glenn : I guess you made a typo. `expect` with `-f`flag names a file from which to read commands, i.e., a script. Not for the debugging purpose. `exp_internal` should be used which you have mentioned already.